# rx dart combine multiple streams to emit value whenever any of the streams emit a value

Tags: flutter, dart, rxdart, combinelatest

In RX dart there is the [`RX.combineLatest`](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/CombineLatestStream-class.html) method to combine the results of a stream using a callback function.
Problem is that it only emits a value when **every** stream has emitted a value. If one has not it does not emit.

> Merges the given Streams into a single Stream sequence by using the combiner function whenever any of the stream sequences emits an item.
> **The Stream will not emit until all streams have emitted at least one item.**

Im trying to combine multiple streams into one stream for validation which should emit false or true when the streams have not emitted or emitted an empty value.

```dart
class FormBloc {
  final BehaviorSubject<bool> _result = BehaviorSubject();
  final BehaviorSubject<String?> _usernameController = BehaviorSubject();
  final BehaviorSubject<String?> _emailController = BehaviorSubject();

  // Will only emit if each stream emitted a value
  // If only username is emitted valid is not emitted
  Stream<bool> get valid$ => Rx.combineLatest2(
    _usernameController.stream, 
    _emailController.stream, 
    (username, email) => username != null || email != null
  );

}
```

How can I join those streams so `valid$` emits a value if **any** of the streams change?

Answer (score 3):

Because all of the solutions here are workarounds Ive implemented my own stream class. Implementation equals the original CombineLatestStream implementation except that it does not wait for all streams to emit before emitting:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:rxdart/src/utils/collection_extensions.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/src/utils/subscription.dart';

class CombineAnyLatestStream<T, R> extends StreamView<R> {

  CombineAnyLatestStream(List<Stream<T>> streams, R Function(List<T?>) combiner) : super(_buildController(streams, combiner).stream);

  static StreamController<R> _buildController<T, R>(
    Iterable<Stream<T>> streams,
    R Function(List<T?> values) combiner,
  ) {

    int completed = 0;

    late List<StreamSubscription<T>> subscriptions;
    List<T?>? values;

    final _controller = StreamController<R>(sync: true);

    _controller.onListen = () {

      void onDone() {
        if (++completed == streams.length) {
          _controller.close();
        }
      }

      subscriptions = streams.mapIndexed((index, stream) {

        return stream.listen(
          (T event) {
            final R combined;

            if (values == null) return;

            values![index] = event;

            try {
              combined = combiner(List<T?>.unmodifiable(values!));
            } catch (e, s) {
              _controller.addError(e, s);
              return;
            }

            _controller.add(combined);
          },
          onError: _controller.addError,
          onDone: onDone
        );
      }).toList(growable: false);

      if (subscriptions.isEmpty) {
        _controller.close();
      } else {
        values = List<T?>.filled(subscriptions.length, null);
      }
    };

    _controller.onPause = () => subscriptions.pauseAll();
    _controller.onResume = () => subscriptions.resumeAll();
    _controller.onCancel = () {
      values = null;
      return subscriptions.cancelAll();
    };

    return _controller;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating new stream which emits current value and listen the stream is my best practice.

```dart
class FormBloc {
  final BehaviorSubject<bool> _result = BehaviorSubject();
  final BehaviorSubject<String?> _usernameController = BehaviorSubject();
  final BehaviorSubject<String?> _emailController = BehaviorSubject();

  final _usernameStreamController = StreamController<String?>()
    ..add(_usernameController.value)
    ..addStream(_usernameController.stream);
  final _emailStreamController = StreamController<String?>()
    ..add(_emailController.value)
    ..addStream(_emailController.stream);

  Stream<bool> get valid$ => Rx.combineLatest2(
    _usernameStreamController.stream,  // use streamController instead
    _emailStreamController.stream,  // use streamController instead
    (username, email) => username != null || email != null
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of combining multiple streams, you can use one `BehaviorSubject<Map<String, String?>>` to emit changes in username or email.

[`add`](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/Subject/add.html) either changed\submitted username or email to the `BehaviorSubject`

```dart
_usernameEmailController.add({"uname": value},);
```

or

```dart
_usernameEmailController.add({"email": value},);
```

so that you can validate the inputs by listening to it. I used `StreamBuilder` to display the emitted values,

```dart
            StreamBuilder<Map<String, String?>>(
              stream: _usernameEmailController.stream
                  .map((data) {
                    _r = {..._r, ...data};
                    return _r;
                  }),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                return Column(
                  children: [
                    Text(snapshot.data.toString()),
                    if (snapshot.hasData)
                      Text(
                          "Is valid?: "
                          "${(snapshot.data!["uname"] != null && snapshot.data!["uname"]!.isNotEmpty) || (snapshot.data!["email"] != null && snapshot.data!["email"]!.isNotEmpty)}"
                      ),
                  ],
                );
              },
            ),
```

checkout the my solution on DartPad [here](https://dartpad.dev/?id=9aceb01992dd187469643877aa0e3a28).

In the DartPad I have used `StreamController` instead of `BehaviorSubject` as DartPad doesn't support `rxdart` Package.
But you can replace line 40 in DartPad

```dart
final StreamController<Map<String, String?>> _usernameEmailController =
        StreamController();
```

with

```dart
final BehaviorSubject<Map<String, String?>> _usernameEmailController =
        BehaviorSubject();
```

If you want to use `BehaviorSubject`.

Answer (score 0):

You could seed your BehaviorSubjects with a default value of null:

```
  final BehaviorSubject<String?> _usernameController = BehaviorSubject().seeded(null);
  final BehaviorSubject<String?> _emailController = BehaviorSubject().seeded(null);
```

Another possibility would be to give the combined stream a seed value:

```
Rx.combineLatest2(
    _usernameController.stream, 
    _emailController.stream, 
    (username, email) => username != null || email != null
  ).sharedValueSeeded(false);
```